# ASP.NET MVC Custom Validation Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have created a custom validation attribute for validating dates in the format of MM/dd/yyyy by extending the RegularExpressionAttribute class. When I apply this attribute to a string property in my model which represents a date, it seems to work fine. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to extend the functionality of this validation attribute to work for DateTime properties as well.

Here is what my class looks like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidDateAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    private const string pattern = @"((^(10|12|0?[13578])([/])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(11|0?[469])([/])(30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(2[0-8]|1[0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2468][048]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([3579][26]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][13579][26])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][13579][26])$))";

    static ValidDateAttribute()
    {
        // necessary to enable client side validation
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(ValidDateAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
    }

    public ValidDateAttribute()
        : base(pattern)
    {
    }
}
```

As stated, everything already seems to be working when the attribute is used as shown below:

```
[DisplayName("Date of birth")]
[ValidDate(ErrorMessage = "Invalid date of birth")]
public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

But how could I check the data type in the validation attribute and, in the case of a DateTime property, apply the same validation to `DateOfBirth.ToString(MM/dd/yyyy)` such that the following would work:

```
[DisplayName("Date of birth")]
[ValidDate(ErrorMessage = "Invalid date of birth")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: a datetime property will never ever be an invalid date. So no need for the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the value to a string in the validation process by overriding IsValid in the following manner:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
   try
   {
      value = value.ToString();
      return base.IsValid(value);
   }
   catch { }
   return base.IsValid(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done what I was intending to do (after I modified the .ToString to match my format specification). Although it seems @Juan M. Elosegui is right and the attribute may be redundant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [blogpost](http://www.mfranc.com/programming/asp-net-mvc-regular-expression-attribute-testingdatetime-validation-problem/) by Michal Franc, you can use the `DisplayFormat` attribute to enforce the use a specific format when applying the validation of a regular expression.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```